# Uncaught TypeError: e.charAt is not a function in kendo grid

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am using kendo UI grid. When I try to draw grid I get the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: e.charAt is not a function

Here's my code:

```
var columns = [{title: 'id', field: '["id 1"]', encoded: false}];
var dataSource = {data: [{'id 1': '<span style="background: yellow; color: black;">21</span>' } , {'id 1': '<span style="background: yellow; color: black;">21</span>' }]}

    $("#grid").kendoGrid({
        dataSource: dataSource,
        scrollable: true,
        groupable: true,
        sortable: true,
        filterable: {
            mode: 'row'
        },
        selectable: "multiple",
        resizable: true,
        pageable: {
            pageSize: 1000,
            buttonCount: 4
        },
        columns: columns,
        height: '95%'
    });
```

You can run my code here:
http://dojo.telerik.com/uNUTI/4

---

It happens after I add the filterable option. Without that option everything would work fine.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting this error, because `field` option for object in `columns` should be a valid property name. Thought you can have object property with white spaces in `JavaScript`, but in `kendo` it should not contain white spaces.

Once you change `id 1` to `id_1`, and `["id 1"]'` to `'id_1'`, you should get expected results

[Kendo Dojo](http://dojo.telerik.com/uNUTI/8)

Comment: yes that works fine. I wanted to handle it without changing my json keys but it sounds that i must change it :)
thanks ;)